# Difference in logic caused by layout segregation

Tags: android

I have a few layouts, which are used against different screen sizes. Difference in markup suggests using different code, for instance menu highlighting.

My guess is that screen resolution should be determined somewhere in a base activity and depending on it appropriate helper should be used.

What is the best way to solve this problem ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do that, the system does. See here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

As it says, applications do not work directly with resolution; applications should be concerned only with screen size and density, as specified by the generalized size (`small` to `xlarge`) and density groups (`ldpi` to `tvdpi`).

You can test it by changing the AVD's property about screen resolution.

Comment: System does what? Say, I have 2 markups. The first has one markup, which is activated for devices with small screen size - the other for big sized and has another markup. Logic of highlighting one header differs from another's, because for the first header I might want to underline an  active tab, but for the second I might want to change background color of an active tab. How this can be handled by the system ?

Comment: System does choosing one alternative to use from your qualified resources according to your device. So you can set different values for different needs. For your example, create `selector` and `string`  values in both directory, with one's having background color and no underline string and the other one's having underlined word but no color. Then you can get them by `res.getDrawable(R.drawable.yourselector);` and `res.getString(R.string.yourstring);`.Is this what you need?